# Catching global "@In attribute requires non-null value" in SEAM 2

Tags: java, jboss5.x, jsf-1.2, seam2, seam-conversation

On `PAGE A` is a table with some data from the database.
by clicking on a row, the page will be forwarded to `PAGE B` and in the controller the entity will be injected

```
@DataModelSelection(value = ENTITY_LIST_NAME)
@Out(value = ENTITY_NAME, scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION, required = false)
private Entity entity;
```

this works as it should.

The problem is, that our users seems to use bookmark for `PAGE B`, so the entity will never be injected because they never visited `PAGE A`

so they always throw this exception

```
@In attribute requires non-null value
```

Is there a global function to catch all `@In attribute requires non-null value` exceptions  and forward the user to `PAGE C` (startpage)?
(of course i can catch this execption on `PAGE B` but this happens not only on one page, we want to handle this exception on every page)

we are using: jboss5 + jsf 1.2 + seam 2

**UPDATE after the answer of EmirCalabuch**:
I also tried the hint from EmirCalabuch with:

```
<page conversation-required="true" no-conversation-view-id="PageC.xhtml" />
```

but the problem is, that the conversation is alive at this moment, to this forwarding to `pageC` never happens...

i also made in the `page.xml` of this page something like:

```
<action execute="#{controller.checkIfEntityIsSet()}" />
<navigation>
    <rule if-outcome="HOME">
            <redirect          
             view-id="/pages/home.xhtml"
            />
        </rule>
</navigation>
```

and in my `Controller.java` i have somthing like this:

```
public String checkIfEntityIsSet(){
        if(getEntity() == null){
            return "HOME"; 
        }
        return "";          
    }
```

but this `checkIfEntityIsSet()` is never called, because the `@In attribute requires non-null value` is thrown before... so this was not a help at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed it now different:

in the `Controller.java` i have for the initialization something like this:

```
@Create
public void initialize() throws MissingMyEntityException {

    if(qualifiedCustomer == null){
        throw new MissingMyEntityException("something wrong");
    }
    ....
}
```

my `MissingMyEntityException.java` looks like this:

```
public class MissingMyEntityException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8640645441429393157L;

    public MissingMyEntityException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

and in the `pages.xml` i have the exception handler like this:

```
<exception class="com.dw.companyName.view.xyz.exception.MissingMyEntityException">
        <redirect view-id="/pages/home.xhtml">
            <message>something went wrong</message>
        </redirect>
    </exception>
```

and this fixed the problem.
but thanks for your help, but it was not working your way :(

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling rules are specified in `pages.xml`. You could include a rule to catch the `org.jboss.seam.RequiredException` that is thrown for that type of error and perform your navigation to page C in it.

This however is not a very clean solution as you would bind that exception to that page and most probably you will have this exception elsewhere and would like to redirect to a different page.

A simpler way of achieving the same result is making the conversation required in `PageB.page.xml` and specifying the view to redirect to when no conversation is active. The page descriptor has an option that allows you to do just that (on `PageB.page.xml`):

```
<page conversation-required="true" no-conversation-view-id="PageC.xhtml" />
```

This tells Seam that if a user tries to display page B and there is no conversation active (which happens when the user gets there from a bookmark), then redirect the user to PageC.xhtml.

Anyway, it takes very little effort to make the page bookmarkable (if you feel your users will be bookmarking it a lot), using page parameters and actions, for example:

In your list page A, instead of an `h:commandLink` or `h:commandButton` for each of the rows that take you to page B, use `s:link` or `s:button`:

```
<h:dataTable var="var" value="#{myList.dataModel}">
...
  <s:link value="PageB.xhtml">
      <f:param name="id" value="#{var.id}" />
  </s:link>
...
</h:dataTable>
```

This will create a link to Page B for each of the entities in the list, passing its ID (for example, `PageB.seam?id=1` in the first row, `PageB.seam?id=2` in the second and so on. These links are bookmarkable.

On `PageB.page.xml` declare the parameter:

```
<param name="id" value="#{myHomeComponent.id}" />
```

Where `myHomeComponent` is a component of type `EntityHome<YourEntity>`. You can then use `#{myHomeComponent.instance}` inside Page B to access the entity selected.

Comment: hi EmirCalabuch, i have updated the question ... thanks for your help, but it hasn't worked, read above for more details!

Comment: Most probably you either have a `begin-conversation` in Page B or the link you're using to call page B has the conversation id parameter in it.

Comment: i tried both, with or without the `begin-conversation` in `pageB.page.xml` - but it was not working. the problem is, that whether there is a conversation or not, the `@In` is always empty, and that make the error.